# Removing pagination numbers

Tags: java, javafx, pagination

I added pagination to my JavaFX app and I'd like to remove this little number below page numbers. How can I do that?

[image]

my code:

Controller:

```
public class ControllerAnswers {

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Pagination pagination;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert pagination != null : "fx:id=\"pagination\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'showAnswers.fxml'.";

}
```

}

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {


        Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/showAnswers.fxml")); 
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, 960,540);

        stage.setScene(scene2);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see your code. Please put it here. Looks like you're printing that number somewhere.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary I added my code. Basically I have nothing more than pagination ... (I wanted to add fxml as well but I wasn't allowed to post that much code with little text )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert pagination != null : "fx:id=\"pagination\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'showAnswers.fxml'.";
    pagination.setStyle("-fx-page-information-visible: false ;");

}
```

Or, if you're using an external css file:

```css
.pagination  {
    -fx-page-information-visible: false ;
}
```